# Diagonalizable Matrix $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I find a matrix $A$ such that $A^2$ is diagonalizable but $A$ is not?

I have tried many different ways, but to no avail. Is there something that I am missing in the question that gives a simple answer?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 7):

Take a matrix $A$ such that $A^2=0$ but $A\neq 0$.

If $A$ were diagonalizable, since the eigenvalues would be all $0$, we would have $A=0$.

Comment: Good point and +1 only for that.

Comment: A^2 matrix (0 0), (0 0) has eigenvalues of 0, with multiplicity of 2, does that not make it non-diagonalizable? and there are no distinct eigenvectors for the A^2 matrix.

Comment: The null matrix _is_ diagonal(izable). There is no need to have distinct eigenvalues (it a sufficient condition to be diagonalizable, but not necessary).